# Linear map and the zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $ V,W $ arbitrary vector spaces and $ v\in V $.

If $ f(v)=0$ for all $ f\in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) $ than $ v=0 $.

I have two ideas but im not completely sure if they are working:

**Idea 1:** Proof by contradiction. Suppose $ v\neq 0 $.

Then for all $ f\in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) $ it is $ \operatorname{Ker}(f)\neq \{0\} $ which means all $ f\in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) $ are not injective. This holds especially for the case $ \dim(V)=\dim(W) $. So $ V  $ and $ W $ are isomorphic which implies the existence of an isomorphism $ f:\space V\to W $. This is a contradiction that $ f $ is not injective.

**Idea 2:** Proof by contraposition. Consider $ v\neq 0 $ and define a linear map as follwos:
$$ f:\underbrace{\space \operatorname{span}(v)\oplus H}_{=:V}\to W, $$

$ H\subset V $ subspace with $ f(v)=:w\neq 0 $ and $ f(h)=0 $ for all $ h\in H $.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do: if $v\neq 0$, we can extend $v$ to a basis of $V$. Assuming there is some nonzero $w\in W$, define $f\colon V\to W$ by extending linearly from $f(v)=w$.

(If $V=0$ then the statement is vacuously true; $V\neq 0$ and $W=0$, the statement is false.)

Comment: What do you mean with "by extending linearly from $ f(v)=w $" and why is the statement false for $ V\neq 0 $ and $ W=0 $?